# Ruby 2.4 Split an Array of Hashes based on a list of acceptable key values

Tags: ruby

I have an array of IDs as listed below:

```
ids = [101153, 87218, 99589, 73109, 80660, 107784, 76392, 101501]
```

I have an array of hashes.

```
[
  {"id"=>107786, "key"=>"ABC-2002", "hidden"=>true, "done"=>false},
  {"id"=>101501, "key"=>"ABC-2002", "hidden"=>true, "done"=>false},
  {"id"=>107786, "key"=>"ABC-2002", "hidden"=>true, "done"=>false},
  {"id"=>107784, "key"=>"ABC-2453", "hidden"=>true, "done"=>false},
  {"id"=>107786, "key"=>"ABC-1345", "hidden"=>true, "done"=>false}
]
```

How do I filter an array of hashes where the ID is present from the array ids?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't very hard. Iterate over hashes with [`select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) to see which ids are known. Use a [`Set`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) for faster lookup.

```
require 'set'

ids = Set.new([101153, 87218, 99589, 73109, 80660, 107784, 76392, 101501])
hashes = [{"id"=>107786, "key"=>"ABC-2002", "hidden"=>true, "done"=>false},{"id"=>101501, "key"=>"ABC-2002", "hidden"=>true, "done"=>false},{"id"=>107786, "key"=>"ABC-2002", "hidden"=>true, "done"=>false},{"id"=>107784, "key"=>"ABC-2453", "hidden"=>true, "done"=>false},{"id"=>107786, "key"=>"ABC-1345", "hidden"=>true, "done"=>false}]

p hashes.select{ |h| ids.include?(h['id']) }
# [{"id"=>101501, "key"=>"ABC-2002", "hidden"=>true, "done"=>false}, {"id"=>107784, "key"=>"ABC-2453", "hidden"=>true, "done"=>false}]
```